# Symfony2 debug log doesn't show username

Tags: symfony, error-logging

I've got a problem with debug logs – if an error occured error log doesn't show which user causes error, but set username blank — `security.DEBUG: Username "" was reloaded from user provider. [] []`

I use custom entity provider written according [cookbook tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html). Other messages – for example `security.INFO: User "......" has been authenticated successfully` is displayed correctly.

Note: I post this problem also to the [forum](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=39729).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and it took me a lot of digging to figure this out.

The problem is that you don't serialize the username in the serialize function of the User object.

Many people use the following for their serialization functions:

```
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize($this->id);
}

public function unserialize($data)
{
    $this->id= unserialize($data);
}
```

This way only the id is known when loading the user from the session token (note this also breaks the ?_switch_user=_exit functionality).

To fix this you should use the following code:

```
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array($this->id,$this->username));
}

public function unserialize($data)
{
    list($this->id,$this->username) = unserialize($data);
}
```

This way the username AND id are available and the issue is fixed.

NOTE: The 'refreshUser' function of your custom user provider will NEVER be used as it will be overruled by the EntityUserProvider!